# pass data between activities in android studio

Tags: java

I'm building an app that needs to pass information from my new Activity to my Main Activity.

I've have tried at the beginning not to work with 2 activities, instead, I just worked with an editText and then passing the information to a textView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
private static int PLACE = 0;
private ArrayList<TextView> notes = new ArrayList<TextView>();
private FloatingActionButton makeNoteFloatingActionButton,saveFloatingActionButton;
private Button setTimeButton;
private int day,month,year,hour,minute;
private int dayFinal,monthFinal,yearFinal,hourFinal,minuteFinal;
private String savedNote;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    makeNoteFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.makeNoteFloatingActionButton);
    saveFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.saveFloatingActionButton);
    setTimeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setTimeButton);


    makeNoteFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,pop.class);
            intent.putExtra("note",);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**AnotherClass**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
private static int PLACE = 0;
private ArrayList<TextView> notes = new ArrayList<TextView>();
private FloatingActionButton makeNoteFloatingActionButton,saveFloatingActionButton;
private Button setTimeButton;
private int day,month,year,hour,minute;
private int dayFinal,monthFinal,yearFinal,hourFinal,minuteFinal;
private String savedNote;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    makeNoteFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.makeNoteFloatingActionButton);
    saveFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.saveFloatingActionButton);
    setTimeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setTimeButton);


    makeNoteFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,pop.class);
            intent.putExtra("note",);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

my goal is to write the text I need and pass it to the main activity in a form of a text view.

Comment: What you want to pass? `putExtra` not completed yet.

Comment: intent.putExtra("key_name",value);    //value --> it can be any data type

complete your question, please.

Comment: In the code, both are the same class code. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Main activity:**

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,pop.class);
        intent.putExtra("note", note);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Another class:**

```
     public class AnotherClass{
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String note = intent.getStringExtra("note");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use startActivityforResult(). So that you always finish the second activity returning the ediText value.

1. Replace startActivity() to startActivityForResult() in first activity.

   ```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,pop.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 101); // 101 is the unique request code
   ```
2. In Second Activity, after getting the value from EdiText do this

   Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.putExtra(“note”, “editTextValue”);

   // Set result and finish this Activity

   ```
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish();
   ```
3. Get the key value of “note” from the onActivityResult() in Activity 1

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

   `switch (requestCode) {

               case 101: // unique request code to obtain the intent data

                   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

               String note = data.getStringExtra(“note”);

                   }

                   break;
           }
       }`

Also make sure you use proper naming conventions use Pop as class name instead of pop